# How to Update database table row when the foreign key has the same value ASP.NET mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-update, insert-update

I have a application where stores can complete a questionnaire. within this application i have two tables db.StoreAud(pk:AuditId) which contains all the stores information, and db.storequests(pk:ReviewId) which holds the all questions information.

AuditId is a foreign key in db.storequests table. Now here is the issue if a store complete the questionnaire the data saves perfectly in the database, however is the same store does the questionnaire again the db.storequests creates a new row in the database with a new primary key value  instead of updating the previous row. Question is how can i update the previous row if the same store does the same questionnaire again. hope this made since.

> db.StoreAUD

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
```

> db.storequests

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public int QuestionOne { get; set; }

    public string QuestionTwo { get; set; }
    public string QuestionThree { get; set; }
    public string QuestionFour { get; set; }
```

> controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StoreQuestions storequestions) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            StoreAudit findingAudit = db.StoreAudit.Find(storequestions.AuditId); // grabbing the id from th store audit table
            findingAudit.ReadOnlyTickBox = true;
            db.StoreQuestions.Add(storequestions);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Audit", new { id = storequestions.AuditId });
        }

        return View(storequestions);
    }
```

Comment: The same way you do it for the StoreAudit.  You first look it up, and if it exists then you update the returned row.  Only add if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Use an `Update()` action for updates.

Comment: i@ErikFunkenbusch i think i have that but was not successful, could you post some code just in case i have made some mistakes if you do not  mind

Comment: @mxmissile could post some example code if possible

Comment: @cedPound  - How do you think you have that?  You take the submitted StoreQuestions and add them to your `db.StoreQuestions` every time, regardless.  You do no looking up of StoreQuestions at all.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch i meant to say that i have done the solution that you recommended however i dont think it fixed my issue reason why i asked you to post the code you think that is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate your update logic into a new `Update` action, following the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update(StoreQuestions storequestions) 
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
              StoreAudit findingAudit = db.StoreAudit.Find(storequestions.AuditId);
              findingAudit.ReadOnlyTickBox = true;

              // update objects here

              db.SaveChanges();
              return RedirectToAction("Details", "Audit", new { id = storequestions.AuditId });
              }

            return View(storequestions);
         }
     }
```

Comment: i still need the update objects as im still not sure on how to do it